# modifier Array+modifier Curve

Tags: modifiers

In this blend file,the first path(A) use a modifier Array+modifier Curve to duplicate ball according to the path=A

But this duplication is not very good because the inclinations of the duplications are not always the same

On the other hand, the inclinations on the same back path are correct.In this back path, I used a constraint follow path

How, using the Array modifier to which we add the Curve modifier, make the slopes of the duplications the same?

see my video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JhsBrzqlYzEyTU7OZ00KwD4tVDy1fTPC/view?usp=sharing

see my blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ABBxKpLjfJJmtA4_-tRG1buSwdzITea/view?usp=sharing

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The *Curve* modifier will deform the object that is duplicated along the curve, while the *Follow Path* won't. If you want to avoid any deformation you can give the *Array* and *Curve* modifiers to a plane instead, keep this plane selected, in the *Object* panel enable the *Instancing > Faces* option, and parent your sphere to this plane. Later, make the plane invisible:

[image]